# Svelte - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm trying to access an Object method outside the `onMount`, but I'm having an issue. I initialized the object inside the `onMount`, and I thought declaring the variable globally would solve the issue, but it didn't, so now I'm at a loss.

This is what I initially had. The code gave me an exception on `slider.getInfo()` saying that the object is possibly 'undefined.'

```
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import {tns} from "tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.js";

let slider

onMount(()=>{
  slider = tns({
    container: ".my-slider",
    slideBy: 1,
    speed: 1000,
    nav: false,
    controls: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayButtonOutput: false,
    responsive: {
      1024: {
        items: 4,
      }
    },
  })
})

let sliderInfo = slider.getInfo()
```

Next I tried putting it in a function and calling the function.

```
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import {tns} from "tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.js";

let slider

onMount(()=>{
  slider = tns({
    container: ".my-slider",
    slideBy: 1,
    speed: 1000,
    nav: false,
    controls: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayButtonOutput: false,
    responsive: {
      1024: {
        items: 4,
      }
    },
  })
})

function setInfo(){
  let sliderInfo = slider.getInfo()
  console.log(sliderInfo)
}
setInfo()
```

This time the code gave me the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInfo')
```

Finally, just because I wanted to see if I could somehow get it to work, I created a button and assigned the function as a handler, and surprisingly this worked. Although I have no idea why this works compared to what I previously tried.

```
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import {tns} from "tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.js";

let slider

onMount(()=>{
  slider = tns({
    container: ".my-slider",
    slideBy: 1,
    speed: 1000,
    nav: false,
    controls: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayButtonOutput: false,
    responsive: {
      1024: {
        items: 4,
      }
    },
  })
})

function setInfo(){
  let sliderInfo = slider.getInfo()
  console.log(sliderInfo)
}

...

<button on:click={setInfo}>Click</button>
```

Unfortunately, the method that worked is not what I'm trying to do, but the first method instead. However I can't figure out why the first method doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onMount` *registers* a callback, which is executed *when* the component mounted as DOM, that is, it will not execute immediately, so it will execute *after* the code you placed below it. (Whether it is wrapped in a function that is called immediately or not, does not matter.)

The click event on the other hand happens much later, after all the DOM already has to be there to interact with it, hence the callback within `onMount` has been called already and `slider` has been set.

How this should be dealt with depends on what you are trying to do. If you just need some code within the component to run, you can just add it to the `onMount` callback as well. If another component needs to do something, you can e.g. [dispatch an event](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher) at the end of `onMount`.

Comment: I just want to call the sliders getInfo() function outside of the ```onMount``` and set it to a variable  (my first section of code). What would I do then? @H.B.

Comment: Why would you have to do that outside? Just declare the variable like `slider` and assign it ***in*** `onMount`. Also, setting a variable is not a goal, it's a means to a goal, it is not what matters here.